# File not found php-fpm + Nginx

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

PHP отдает "File not found" при следующих настройках:

Nginx:

```
server
{
    server_name coderent.local;
    root /www/coderent/web;
    listen 80;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$)
    {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;

        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

PHP:

```
listen 127.0.0.1:9000
user=www
group=www
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
```

Файл app_dev.php точно есть в /www/coderent/web, права в порядке.

tcpdump на 9000-м порту (SCRIPT_FILENAME присутствует):

```
localhost.45548 > localhost.cslistener: Flags [P.], seq 1:969, ack 1, win 683, options [nop,nop,TS val 4177950 ecr 4177950], length 968
E.....@.@.X...........#(.. ...;............
.?...?............................SCRIPT_FILENAME/www/coderent/web/app_dev.php..DOCUMENT_ROOT/www/coderent/web..QUERY_STRING..REQUEST_METHODGET..CONTENT_TYPE..CONTENT_LENGTH..SCRIPT_NAME/app_dev.php..REQUEST_URI/app_dev.php..DOCUMENT_URI/app_dev.php..DOCUMENT_ROOT/www/coderent/web..SERVER_PROTOCOLHTTP/1.1..REQUEST_SCHEMEhttp..GATEWAY_INTERFACECGI/1.1..SERVER_SOFTWAREnginx/1.12.2..REMOTE_ADDR192.168.10.1..REMOTE_PORT56866..SERVER_ADDR192.168.10.15..SERVER_PORT80..SERVER_NAMEcoderent.local..REDIRECT_STATUS200
```

В логах PHP на месте %f вижу "-", т.е. как будто до него не долетел SCRIPT_FILENAME.

Centos7

Nginx 1.12

PHP (php-fpm) 7.2.9 remi

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Глаз уже замылен, могу чего-то очевидного не замечать :(

Comment: А fastcgi точно на 127.0.0.1:9000 слушает?

Comment: Интересно. Взял конфиг, воткнул на тестовый nginx — работает. Предлагаю посмотреть strace'ом на php-fpm при обработке получаемого запроса. Заодно убедимся, что запрос получает именно он. А, да, пока писал, вдруг в голову зашёл вопрос: центось же! Там selinux ничего такого не чудит? Может, у php-fpm не тот /www, что у вас? :)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev спасибо, добрый человек) selinux чудил.

Comment: @Дмитрий оформлю ответ?

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev да, оформляйте

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Одна из наиболее частых причин возникающих на CentOS/RHEL неочевидных ошибок, связанных с доступом к тем или иным ресурсам — SELinux. Имеет смысл проверить, не он ли здесь влияет, путём его временного отключения или [изучения audit.log](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-auditing-system-on-centos-7)